# Migrating a Compact Framework 2.0 App to Windows Phone

Tags: compact-framework, windows-phone, windows-ce

I have a Compact Framework 2.0 application written years ago in VB.NET using VS2005. The application uses a local SQL compact database (.sdf) file. The application has been running on HP iPAQs for years.

I want to look at making this available to Windows Phone users. Any suggestions for the easiest way to do this? When I say easy I mean quick I suppose, the client is not interested in paying for it, so if there was a crude way to implement/achieve it I would be prepared to go that route.

The alternative is building a new Windows Phone app, my first. Which would be fun, but not very good for the balance sheet! Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the only option available is going to be a wholesale rewrite of the application.  If you were strategic in your original design and kept the business logic and UI separate, then that code will transfer pretty easily, but the data access code will have to be rewritten and all of the UI code will have to be rewritten.